# Как пропускать пустые значения в INI файле?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите как пропускать чтение пустых параметров из `INI` файла, чтобы при загрузке формы не выдавало ошибку - *нет логического значения*.

Используется класс `IniFile.cs` подробнее: [link](https://gist.github.com/DamianSuess/e8bf4679b201e07757e97aad944e0395)

Так в файле `INI` выглядит значение:

```
[app-ini]
checkBox1=true
```

Проблема в том, что когда в файле отсутствует значение `checkBox1=true` появляется ошибка для соответствующей строки в коде (пометил комментарием) - *Строка не распознана как действительное логическое значение.*

```
IniFile ini = new IniFile(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%Temp%\\config.ini"));

private void FormControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var saveBox1 = Convert.ToBoolean(ini.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini")); // ошибка здесь
    checkBox1.Checked = saveBox1;
}
```

Comment: Если по бизнес-логике отсутствие параметра не является ошибкой (т.е. параметр является не обязательным) то используйте nullable типы. Заменяйте `boolean` на `boolean?`, используйте значение по умолчанию - конкретика зависит от задачи: я лично вижу более одного варианта решения, но поскольку не озвучено как правильно - то нужно ждать уточнения вопроса. Ну вот ошибка. А как правильно?

Comment: Лучше где то себе это помечать, либо дополнительное поле в вашей структуре сделать, что именно тут не удалось получить данные из ini файла. Но по сути лучше конечно попытаться считать все строки из ini  и если происходит краш, то просто не заполнять данные в конкретное поле (куда вы парсите ini). Но опять же, лучше чтобы в дальнейшем знали, где у вас не удалось получить значение.

Comment: Разберите составную строку на отдельные шаги и посмотрите где происходит ошибка.

Comment: Конкретика такая, чтобы не было использования `if` и `else` и лучше всего через `bool` так как стоит мне, что-то изменить - код не дает, пишет, что нужно использовать только тип `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так подойдет?

```
var saveBox1 = ini.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini");
checkBoxBAT.Checked = (saveBox1 == "true") ? true : false;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Даже не пришлось конвертировать `Convert.ToBoolean` сначала хотел сделать так `var saveBox1 = Convert.ToBoolean(ini.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini") == "true" ? true : false);` но когда сделал с нуля как в ответе, ошибок не выдало. Даже приятнее выглядит.